# Xamaring IPA Archive to store fails

Tags: xamarin, archive

Can't archive an IPA with VS2019 on either Mac or PC. Everything latest version as of today. Works with Debug on device and Simulator. I already have an unlisted version in the store (exposed via Apple Business Manager and redemption codes) working. This is a patch release. Thoughts? Thanks[image]

Comment: Check the log, this window is very scarce with information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.